# Use of privilege escalation in a secure environment with become/ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to perform administrative tasks with ansible in a secure environment:

On the server :

- root is not activated
- we connect throught ssh to a not sudoer account (public/private key, I usually use ssh-agent not to type the passphrase each and every time)
- change to a user which belongs to sudo group
- then we perform administrative tasks

Here is the command I execute :

```
ansible-playbook install_update.yaml -K
```

the playbook :

```
    ---
- hosts: server
  tasks:
    - name: install
      apt:
        name: python-apt
        state: latest
    - name: update
      become: yes
      become_user: admin_account
      become_method: su
      apt:
        name: "*"
        state: latest
```

The hosts file :

```
    [server]
192.168.1.50 ansible_user=ssh_account
```

But this doesn't allow me to do the tasks: for this particular playbook, It raises this error :

```
fatal: [192.168.1.50]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "'/usr/bin/apt-get upgrade --with-new-pkgs ' failed: E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)\nE: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?\n", "rc": 100, "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

which gives the idea that there is a privilege issue...

I would be really glad if someone had an idea !!

Best regards

PS: I have added to sudoers file the nopasswd for this admin account and if I run this playbook it works :

```
---
- hosts: pi
  tasks:
    - name: install
      apt:
        name: python-apt
        state: latest
    - name: update
      become: yes
      become_method: su
      become_user: rasp_admin
      shell: bash -c "sudo apt update"
```

I guess that when I changed user via su command from ssh_account, I would like to specify that with the admin_accound, my commands have to be run with sudo, but I failed finding the right way to do it...any ideas ??

PS: a workarround is to download a shell file et execute it with ansible but I find it is not satisfying...any other idea ?

Comment: `admin_account` obviously does not have the sufficient privileges to acquire the `dpkg` lock. Fix your permissions.

Comment: do a `sudo -l -U admin_account` to whether this account is `sudo` or not

Comment: @Zeitounator : thanks for your remark. I agree it looks like a privilege issue, but when I am connected on the server as admin_account I ran run the command without a problem.

Comment: @JBone: getent group|grep sudo shows that this account definitely belongs to sudo group, thanks for your remark.